# Cross-references: managing references when there are 1000+ across 100 pages

Tags: cross-referencing, equations, emacs, auctex

I am using Emacs with AUCTeX in case that matters.

I have many `\label`ed items and was wondering if there is a way to bring up a list of them?  I hate having to scroll through to the document to find the `\label{eq:...}`, `\label{fig:...}`, etc. since I can't remember all the names.  Is there an easy way to see a list of them when I am looking to cross-reference one.

So right now I am trying to reference two equations, but I can't remember the label name.  How can I obtain it without scrolling through the `.tex` file?

What do I do from here?  I can't get to the `\ref` option no matter what I hit or do.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `C-c )`?  Hit `<space>` to get `reftex` to bring up an outline of the document and offer options in the mini-buffer.  (Note: if you are using `AUCTeX`, you are also probably using `reftex` by default.)

Comment: @jon after I hit `C-c )`, I get a choice select reference format: `[^M] \ref` and `[p] \pageref`, but whenever I hit `space` as you suggested, `^M`, or try to navigate to it to hit enter, the buffer disappears.

Comment: That doesn't seem right.  Assuming I have some `\label`s and so forth, typing `C-c )` brings up in the mini-buffer: `Label type: [ efinNst]   (?=Help)`.  Hitting `<SPC>` at this point splits the main buffer and in the bottom one the document is parsed, showing `\label`s in a skeleton outline of the document.  However, if I wait too long to make a selection, I get in the bottom half `SELECT A LABEL TYPE` and in the mini-buffer `Label type: [ efinNst]`, and hitting `<SPC>` at then brings me to the outline with `Select: [n]ext [p]revious [r]escan [ ]context e[x]tern [q]uit RET [?]HELP+more`.

Comment: Of course (my fault)!  This should be preliminary: it is asking you if you want to *use* `\ref` or `\pageref`! See the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex.html#SEC13).  (The trouble with AUCTeX is that there is *too* much functionality and you forget half or more of everything you've learned every month or so....)

Comment: From the screen shot, it looks like you should just hit `<RET>` and it will default to `\ref`, whereas you should type `p <RET>` if you want `\pageref`.  However, I don't see the manual open at all in the screenshot but a `*RefTeX Select*` buffer.  The `^M` is a carriage return.

Comment: @jon so return did the trick

Comment: If you don't want to be prompted for the reference format put this in your `.emacs`: `(setq reftex-ref-macro-prompt nil)`

Comment: May be it is advisable to ask @jon to convert his comment into an answer to have more strength/perspective instead of self answering(last resort).

Comment: @texenthusiast I told him it worked and waited about 3 weeks for him to do so.  I answered to remove it from the answer queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my question from Jon's comment so I can remove it from the unanswered list.

Per Jon's comment,

"From the screen shot, it looks like you should just hit  and it will default to `\ref`, whereas you should type p  if you want `\pageref`. However, I don't see the manual open at all in the screenshot but a *RefTeX Select* buffer. The `^M` is a carriage return."

Comment: @texenthusiast -- my fault: I forgot about this.  Just glad to have helped, anyway.